# What does forward slash refer to in the "url" property of ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am integrating some Angular and ui-router into my start-up's website and I have come across an issue with getting ui-router and ui-view to work. It lead to wonder what the `/` in the url property of `.state` points to. Does it point to where the Angular app is declared or somewhere else? Essentially I'd appreciate any feedback into how I can fix my issue. (See "careers" state in "App Module" code below to see what I am referring to)

[As you can see here, it's not currently working.](https://chronasleep.com/careers/)

**App Module**

```
var careersApp = angular.module("ultradiaCareers", ["ui.router", "services"]);

careersApp.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider){
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
$stateProvider
    .state('careers', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "openings.html",
        controller: "CareersController"
    })
    .state('positions', {
        url: "/position/:id",
        templateUrl: "position.html",
        controller: "PositionsController"
    });
});
```

**Controllers**

```
angular.module("ultradiaCareers")

.controller('CareersController', ["$scope", "GetOpenings", function ($scope, GetOpenings) {
    "use strict";

    GetOpenings.openings.then(function (positions) {
        $scope.openings = positions.data;
    });

}])

.controller('PositionsController', ["$scope", "$http", "$stateParams", "GetOpenings", function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, GetOpenings) {
    "use strict";

    GetOpenings.openings.then(function (positions) {
        $scope.openings = positions.data;
        $scope.positon = positions.data[GetOpenings.getPositionById($scope.openings, $stateParams.id)];
    });


}]);
```

**Index HTML**

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body ng-app="ultradiaCareers">

<div ui-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Service for JSON**

```
var careersServices = angular.module("services", [])

.factory("GetOpenings", ["$http", function ($http) {
    "use strict";

    var GetOpenings = this, i;

    GetOpenings.openings = $http.get("/careers/positions.json");

    return {

        openings: GetOpenings.openings,
        getPositionById: function (data, value) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].pid == value) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Hi @sams-serif, actually what are you trying to do? Do you want to stay in the url "/" while go to state `careers`?

Comment: Hey @AbhilashPA, I'm trying to display the template of the careers state in the index.html file via ui-router. I've only ever done this on smaller apps and I'm just wondering if I am doing something incorrectly to cause this behavior.

Comment: ok. you can use `otherwise("/")` to route your default state. Or you can use `$state.go('careers')` in your `run` method.